# Why does the root logger accept logs from child loggers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I don't understand the interactions between the root logger and child loggers:

```
import logging

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# 1. SOME LOGGER
logger = logging.getLogger( 'logger' ) 
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# 2. ROOT LOGGER
rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
rootLogger.setLevel( logging.CRITICAL )
fh = logging.FileHandler('root.log')
fh.setLevel( logging.DEBUG )
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
rootLogger.addHandler(fh)

#
logger.info( 'hello' )
```

The last line `logger.info( 'hello' )` should be

- accepted by `logger` because it has `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)`
- rejected by the `rootLogger` because it has `rootLogger.setLevel( logging.CRITICAL )`

But at the end of my script, I have a file `root.log` containing `hello`. Why doesn't the `CRITICAL` level block the message for `rootLogger`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because the `logger` object is only inheriting the `FileHandler` object you assigned to `rootLogger`, not the log-level. Your `Logger` object sets its own log-level, so the parent's log-level won't be used at all. This means that logging through `logger` will check the log-level of the `logger` itself (which is `INFO`), and then the level of the inherited `FileHandler` (which is `DEBUG`) - it doesn't check the log-level of the parent `rootLogger` object. Because both `logger` and `FileHandler` are set to `INFO` level or above, you see `'hello'` get logged.

If you don't want `logger` to inherit the handlers from `rootLogger`, set the [`propagate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) attribute to '0' on the `logger` object:

```
logger = logging.getLogger( 'logger' ) 
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.propagate = 0
```

If you want the child logger to inherit the parent's log-level, set the child log-level to `NOTSET`:

```
logger = logging.getLogger( 'logger' ) 
logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
```